# Ubuntu 14 mount.cifs with credentials did not work

Tags: mount, cifs, credentials

I can mount the Windows share drive in the following way:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 -o user=wega,password=1234
```

but I can not in this way:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 -o credentials=/root/.smbcredential_2

cat .smbcredential_2
username=wega   
password=1234
```

**Debugging with strace**

```
strace -f -e trace=mount mount -t cifs //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 -o credentials=/root/.smbcredential_2
Process 3338 attached
Process 3339 attached
[pid  3339] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid  3338] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3339, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid  3338] mount("//192.168.1.151/_wymiana", ".", "cifs", 0, "ip=192.168.1.151,unc=\\\\192.168.1"...) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
[pid  3338] +++ exited with 32 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3338, si_status=32, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 32 +++
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: When you type in the command is your command prompt a "$" or a "#"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and verify that you don't have any spaces or any other invisible characters after the username and password in your credential file.

Having extra spaces would change the credentials.

Your `cat` command shows several extra characters after the username entry.

Comment: I changed `username=wega
password=wega@1qazxsw2` and still the same

Comment: I reboot system and is ok:)

Comment: I forgot to thank you , thank you for your help L. D. James

Comment: @Mantykora7 I don't think you should have changed the password.  Just remove the spaces from the previous file.

Comment: @Mantykora7 Glad it's working.  Thanks for the acknowledgement.  FYI, by the way, a reboot should not have been a criterion.  Users are added to systems and passwords are changed and updated on production servers that go months and years without being rebooted.